# Amazon CloudWatch Monitoring Scripts different from df command

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

Hello there i have a ec2 on aws and i installed Amazon CloudWatch Monitoring Scripts in it.
It is working great but i have 1 issue when i run df command on ec2 it showing it's / disk usage 70% but monitoring script shows/sends 66%. Why is this happening and how to solve this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out from [here](http://larsmichelsen.com/open-source/answer-why-does-df-k-show-wrong-percentage-usage/).

In short it was because of ext3 usage of hard drive.

Comment: Well, it's good that you found your own answer, but you haven't really captuted the essence of the solution in the answer that you've posted.  If the off-site link goes stale, this answer isn't helpful, because "ext3 usage" isn't really accurate.  It's 5% reserved capacity for the superuser, and ext3 isn't the only filesystem that can do this.

Comment: Yes after this i did little research on my temp server about ext3 usage. Its usage not exactly 5% but round 5% (4-6%).

After all all i want to do send alert when disk usage reach 90% on computer. So this accurate is enough for me to do that.